# Updating Lightning EmailTemplates using REST api

Tags: lightning, rest-api, email, api, email-template

I'm trying to replace links within email templates created by the lightning builder programmatically.

I've managed to get the sobject ID of an email template using the REST api, but when I try to update it I get a confusing message:

Request:

`https://{my org}-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v52.0/sobjects/EmailTemplate/{the id}`

Request body (json):

```json
{
    "HtmlValue": "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\" />  <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initialscale=1.0\" /><meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=edge\" /><style type=\"text/css\">@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {slot[style] {margin-right: 0 !important;}.columnDiv {margin-right: 0 !important;}}@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {slot[style] {margin-bottom: 0 !important;}.columnDiv {margin-bottom: 0 !important;}}</style><style type=\"text/css\">@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {.contentbuilderBaseColumnRow .columnCell {display:inline-block;width:100%}}</style><style type=\"text/css\">.contentpageDefaultEmailTemplatePageTemplate .contentRoot {width: 600px;}@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {.contentpageDefaultEmailTemplatePageTemplate .contentRoot{width: 320px;}}</style> </head> <body>  <table class=\"contentpageDefaultEmailTemplatePageTemplate\" style=\"background-color: #E9EAEC;\" role=\"presentation\" id=\"contentpage_emailTemplateBodyContent\" width=\"100%\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\"><tr><td width=\"100%\" align=\"center\"><table class=\"contentRoot\" style=\"background-color: #FFFFFF;\" role=\"presentation\" width=\"600\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\"><tr><td style=\"padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;\"><table class=\"contentbuilderBaseColumnRow\" style=\"background-color:;\" role=\"presentation\" width=\"100%\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\"><tr valign=\"top\"><td width=\"100%\" class=\"columnCell\" style=\"vertical-align: top;display: inline-block\"><table style=\"width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; word-break:break-word;\"><tr><td><a href=\"test\" target=\"_blank\">test-text</a></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></body></html>"
}
```

(Confusing) Response:

```json
[
    {
        "message": "For Lightning templates, use the HTML Value field instead of the Email Body field.: Email Body",
        "errorCode": "FIELD_INTEGRITY_EXCEPTION",
        "fields": [
            "Body"
        ]
    }
]
```

I am using the Html Value field- not the body.  Is this a bug in the Salesforce API? If so - is there a better way to update this value?

Edit:

Updating the call to v59 just makes it return not found, which is even more confusing

`https://{my org}-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v59.0/sobjects/EmailTemplate/{ the id }`

body:

```json
{
    "HtmlValue": "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\" />  <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initialscale=1.0\" /><meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=edge\" /><style type=\"text/css\">@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {slot[style] {margin-right: 0 !important;}.columnDiv {margin-right: 0 !important;}}@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {slot[style] {margin-bottom: 0 !important;}.columnDiv {margin-bottom: 0 !important;}}</style><style type=\"text/css\">@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {.contentbuilderBaseColumnRow .columnCell {display:inline-block;width:100%}}</style><style type=\"text/css\">.contentpageDefaultEmailTemplatePageTemplate .contentRoot {width: 600px;}@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {.contentpageDefaultEmailTemplatePageTemplate .contentRoot{width: 320px;}}</style> </head> <body>  <table class=\"contentpageDefaultEmailTemplatePageTemplate\" style=\"background-color: #E9EAEC;\" role=\"presentation\" id=\"contentpage_emailTemplateBodyContent\" width=\"100%\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\"><tr><td width=\"100%\" align=\"center\"><table class=\"contentRoot\" style=\"background-color: #FFFFFF;\" role=\"presentation\" width=\"600\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\"><tr><td style=\"padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;\"><table class=\"contentbuilderBaseColumnRow\" style=\"background-color:;\" role=\"presentation\" width=\"100%\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\"><tr valign=\"top\"><td width=\"100%\" class=\"columnCell\" style=\"vertical-align: top;display: inline-block\"><table style=\"width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; word-break:break-word;\"><tr><td><a href=\"test\" target=\"_blank\">test-text</a></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></body></html>"
}
```

Response

```json
[
    {
        "errorCode": "NOT_FOUND",
        "message": "The requested resource does not exist"
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Fixed it - well for my use case anyway - looks like this update is broken in v59.0. (and 52 apparently).  Updated my call to v58

`https://{ my org }-dev-ed.my.salesforce.com/services/data/v58.0/sobjects/EmailTemplate/{the id}`

```json
{
    "HtmlValue": "<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=UTF-8\" />  <meta name=\"viewport\" content=\"width=device-width, initialscale=1.0\" /><meta http-equiv=\"X-UA-Compatible\" content=\"IE=edge\" /><style type=\"text/css\">@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {slot[style] {margin-right: 0 !important;}.columnDiv {margin-right: 0 !important;}}@media screen and (min-width: 480px) {slot[style] {margin-bottom: 0 !important;}.columnDiv {margin-bottom: 0 !important;}}</style><style type=\"text/css\">@media screen and (max-width: 480px) {.contentbuilderBaseColumnRow .columnCell {display:inline-block;width:100%}}</style><style type=\"text/css\">.contentpageDefaultEmailTemplatePageTemplate .contentRoot {width: 600px;}@media only screen and (max-width: 480px) {.contentpageDefaultEmailTemplatePageTemplate .contentRoot{width: 320px;}}</style> </head> <body>  <table class=\"contentpageDefaultEmailTemplatePageTemplate\" style=\"background-color: #E9EAEC;\" role=\"presentation\" id=\"contentpage_emailTemplateBodyContent\" width=\"100%\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\"><tr><td width=\"100%\" align=\"center\"><table class=\"contentRoot\" style=\"background-color: #FFFFFF;\" role=\"presentation\" width=\"600\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\"><tr><td style=\"padding-top: 10px; padding-bottom: 10px; padding-left: 10px; padding-right: 10px;\"><table class=\"contentbuilderBaseColumnRow\" style=\"background-color:;\" role=\"presentation\" width=\"100%\" cellpadding=\"0\" cellspacing=\"0\"><tr valign=\"top\"><td width=\"100%\" class=\"columnCell\" style=\"vertical-align: top;display: inline-block\"><table style=\"width: 100%; border-collapse: collapse; word-break:break-word;\"><tr><td><a href=\"test\" target=\"_blank\">test-text</a></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr></table></td></tr><tr><td>Made a change!</td></tr></table></body></html>"
}
```

Response (none, but status code 204, and requesting the sobject again shows the updated one)